# GWT radiobutton UI Design

Tags: gwt

how to give space between radio button and text in gwt.

what i did,i took one radio button,

```
RadioButton radioOn = new RadioButton("radio", "On");
```

and then simply took horizantal panel and set it's text,

```
HorizontalPanel accessPointHorizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
accessPointHorizontalPanel.setSpacing(5);
accessPointHorizontalPanel.add(new HTML("Access Point:"));
accessPointHorizontalPanel.add(radioOn);
```

i have button on web page with like this: Access Point:(radiobutton symbol)On

i want space between them.i search in google but don't have satisfied answer.
please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about IE6 (and I hope so), I'd use an attribute selector for the radio:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the above will get the single input radio, not its label. If you want to get the label and apply a `margin-left`, use `input[type="radio"] + label {...}`.

Comment: hi i have done it through

panel.add(new Label(){{setHtml("<B><font size='2'>"+name+"</font></B>");setWidth(200);addStyleName("gwt-uos-label");}});

try it.it's good and working solution